# 指定urlが、現在urlと比較して、同一生成元ポリシーかどうか条件分岐したい

Tags: javascript

**質問**
・どう書けば良いでしょうか？

**現状**
・うまくいかない
・意図しない結果(NG)になります…

```
var url="××";

var currentUrl = location.origin;

if ( url.match(/currentUrl/)) {
 //同一生成元ポリシーOK
}else{
 //同一生成元ポリシーNG
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url.match(/currentUrl/)`だと、"currentUrl"という文字列に対するマッチングになってしまうので、うまくいきませんね。
こんな感じでもいいですか？

```
if (url.indexOf(location.origin) === 0) {
```

Comment: `location.origin`は`http://example.jp`といった文字列を返してくるので、`http://example.jp:81`だったり`http://example.jp@example.com`が意図せずsame originと判定されてしまいます

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かに`url`の値がそういうのだとまずいですね。`url.indexOf(location.origin + '/') === 0`なら良さそうでしょうか？

Comment: `http://username@example.jp`と`http://example.jp`がsame originと判定されない問題もあるので、別に回答したとおりパーサを通した方が良いと思います

Answer (score 3):

[Qiitaの投稿にあるcreateElementで作った`a` DOMオブジェクトを使ってパースさせる方法](http://qiita.com/_shimizu/items/850040f8625d886e523b)を参考にしました。

originメソッドはIEがサポートしてないようですが、それでいいのであれば

```
var url=new URL("http://example.jp");

if( location.origin == url.origin){
    //same origin
}
```

でよさそうです。

IEもサポートするのであれば、上記URLの手法でURLをパースした上で、originメソッドを使わずにprotocolとhostを個別に比較する必要がありそうです。

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
a.href="http://example.jp";

if(  location.protocol == element.protocol && location.host == element.host) {
    //same origin
}
```